# How to adjust and label x ticks on line graph created from dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using this code to create and graph a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

dictionary = {'Q1_19': 3.4, 'Q1_20': 3.2, 'Q2_19': 3.9, 'Q2_20': 2.7, 
              'Q3_19': 3.8, 'Q3_20': 2.3, 'Q4_19': 4.0, 'Q4_20': 0.0}

random_vals = {
    'Q1':['Q1_19', 'Q1_20'],
    'Q2':['Q2_19', 'Q2_20'],
    'Q3':['Q3_19', 'Q3_20'],
    'Q4':['Q4_19', 'Q4_20']}

x_ticks = []
vals = []
line_labels = ['2019','2020']
x = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4']
for x_tick, val_list in random_vals.items():
    x_ticks += [x_tick]
    vals += [[0.0 if math.isnan(dictionary[v]) else dictionary[v] for v in val_list]]

df = pd.DataFrame(vals, index=x_ticks, columns=line_labels)
```

Subsequent dataframe looks like this:

```
   2019 2020
Q1  3.4 3.2
Q2  3.9 2.7
Q3  3.8 2.3
Q4  4.0 0.0
```

After graphing this dataframe using `graph = df.plot()` how do I then make sure 'graph' has 4 labelled tick marks on the x-axis, one for each quarter?

what graph currently looks like

[image: what graph currently looks like]

Answer (score 1):

This adjustment seemed to do the trick:

```
df.plot(xticks=range(len(x_ticks)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like just `df.plot()` works, and gives:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why that worked for you but not me? Mine still looks like the image I posted above

Comment: Probably default settings